# How to stop a console process in heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, console

I'm using ps:stop but this doesn't work.

Does anyone know if they have recently updated?

Thanks!

```
M-MacBook-Pro:SN m$ heroku ps
Process       State               Command
------------  ------------------  ------------------------------
run.5         up for 17h          rails c
web.1         up for 1h           bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
web.2         up for 1h           bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker.1      up for 1h           bundle exec rake jobs:work
M-MacBook-Pro:SN m$ heroku ps:stop run.5
 !   ps:stop is not a heroku command. See 'heroku help'.
```

Comment: Could you be running an old version of the heroku CLI? - what does `heroku help ps` give you also what's the output of `heroku version`.

Comment: I'll add as an answer so you can mark as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could be using an old version of the Heroku CLI, might me making sure that you are up to date to be able to use the `heroku ps` command